# Can a FTP server use control port other than 21 (default control port)?

Tags: ftp, port

Can a ftp server listen on any other port than 21 (default control port to which any FTP client initiates the connection to)? If yes, how does the client know on which port it has to initiate the connection to?

Is it an RFC violation to use non-default control port on the server? Please note that I am not asking about server side data port.

Thanks
Sankar

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can, but you must tell the client to use another port (the client can not figure out the port itself automatically).

For example (if you set the port to 2121):

```
ftp://example.com:2121
```

Comment: According to http://lftp.yar.ru./news.html#2.0.2 , some ftp client support srv

Comment: wow, nice, i am not fammiliar with this client. But most clients still just try on port 21, and fail (unles user set the port).